# Looping through two rows of data in excel to match cells and add a string to new cell in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of unique values(A) and a second set of columns with values from the set of unique values(B) and another value(C).

Essentially what I am trying to do is loop through all of the unique values A, and then have an inner loop to go through B which could have the same value from A multiple times, and every time it finds a match, add the value (C) to a concatenated string, then when it has found all those values, to insert that into a new cell and move on to the next A values and do the same.

I'm getting a variety of errors and have tried this several ways, but not using VBA often at all, I'm not getting there and haven't found any good  info on this.

Any help or ideas on how I could do this would be helpful, below is the code that I'm using.

This is essentially what the spreadsheet looks like

```
Column A ----- Column B -------- Column C 

A-----------------A---------------stringA  
A-----------------A --------------stringB
C-----------------B---------------stringC
```

So in my new column, next to column A I would have inserted stringA, stringB.

Hopefully that makes sense.

```
Sub contactStuff()
    Dim roleName As String
    Dim rowNumber As Integer
    Dim userName As String
    Dim userRoleName As String
    Dim concatString As String
    Dim roleNumber As Integer
    roleNumber = 2
    rowNumber = 2
    For Each c In Worksheets("parentRoles").Range("C2:C856").Cells
        roleName = c.Value
        Do
            userRoleName = Worksheets("parentRoles").Range("G" & rowNumber)
            If userRoleName = roleName Then
                contactString = concatString & ", " & Worksheets("parentRoles").Range("E" & rowNumber)
                rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
            End If
        Loop While userRoleName = roleName
        Worksheets("parentRoles").Range("D" & roleNumber).Value = concatString
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim colA As Long
    Dim colB As Long
    Dim newString As String

    ' gets the last row in a column '
    colA = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colB = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ' First loop takes you through each unique value in column A '
        For a = 1 To colA
            newString = ""
            ' For every unique value in column A loop through column B and get the value from column C to build your string '
            For b = 1 To colB
                If .Cells(b, 2) = .Cells(a, 1) Then
                    If newString <> "" Then
                        newString = newString & ", " & Cells(b, 3) ' gets the value from col C and adds it to your new string '
                    Else
                        newString = Cells(b, 3)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            ' Place the new string in column D'
            .Cells(a, 4).Value = newString
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

With the following columns:

```
Col A   Col B   Col C
a         a       1 
b         b       1 
c         c       1 
          a       2 
          b       2 
          c       2 
          a       3 
          b       3 
          c       3
```

You would end up with the following output in Col D:

```
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
```